Indian visa and 180 rule
I have a new passport and I'm applying for a new visa for India. Is my old passport linked to my new one in any way? There's a 180-day visa rule per calendar year and
I stayed on my old passport and visa 120 days... However, I wish to return 1st October. Hope that makes sense.

The restrictions for the amount of time you can spend in a country are not linked to your document, but to your person.

Is my old passport linked to my new one in any way? Of course it is. Via your personal details and biometrics in the passport chip, and in India’s records relating to the issue of your existing visa and your entry/exit.

All rules about visiting India and other countries apply to you, not to a passport. Changing your passport makes no difference.
Previous visits are recorded as being by you, not your passport. They will know about all previous visits.
Assuming you meet all the other criteria for entry you can visit for a maximum of sixty days in the remainder of the year.
